# Consolidate three iOS apps into one

Tags: ios, app-store

I have three iOS apps in the App Store: Myco Free, Myco and [Myco Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myco-pro/id646736059).
The apps are quite dated, the latest update was in 2015. I would like to update them now in several regards.

When I tried to publish an update to Myco Pro (End of 2018). The update got
rejected by Apple with the following reason:

> This app duplicates the content and functionality of other apps
>   submitted by you or another developer to the App Store, which is
>   considered a form of spam.

I gather that Apple does not want several apps with slightly different feature sets but rather one app with in-app purchases to unlock pro features.

What is the best practice to do this in my case?

- Can I just remove Myco from the App Store and resubmit Myco Pro, still keeping Myco Free? Would Apple accept a free version and a pro version in the App Store?
- Would it be possible to "update" all customers of Myco to Myco Pro?
- If I implement one "consolidated" App with in-app purchases. How can I migrate existing customers of Myco and Myco Pro to that new app, with the respective features unlocked?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I just remove Myco from the App Store and resubmit Myco Pro, still keeping Myco Free? Would Apple accept a free version and a pro version in the App Store?

Keeping multiple apps by same developer with same concept does not make sense e.g. there are multiple chess apps but from different developer and none of developer have different chess app with different unlocks (like pro, ultimate, free etc.). Better maintain single app for every user.

> If I implement one "consolidated" App with in-app purchases. How can I migrate existing customers of Myco and Myco Pro to that new app, with the respective features unlocked?

Basically In-app purchase have restore functionality, so you can restore user account from there.

Restore only works when transaction done only from IAP. If your transaction is not from IAP them check your user type (free, pro..) from your server DB before he make any transaction.

Comment: Thanks. Currently all versions of Myco are just simple client apps. No server. So I think it is basically impossible to "migrate" customers from two existing apps to a new consolidated app. Or do you see any way to achieve this?

Comment: @jbandi Is your app have APNS then you can send msg to your users "Support of this app is no longer available, please download our new app." It is little bit negative but fine too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tips. (my apps don't have APN). But even if they had: How would I give a customer of "Myco Pro" access to the pro features in the newly downloaded app, without forcing him to bay again?

Comment: @jbandi How you maintaining the pro app now?

Comment: @ahiya_boy People who buy the Pro app get the pro features, simple as that! There is no upgrade from the Standard app to the Pro app.